# Ceiling in CP-SAT

Tags: python, constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat

In a scheduling problem. I want to assign vacations proportionally to the days worked. Right now I have a working solution using multiple boolean flags but it doesn't scale very well.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from math import ceil

model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

days = model.NewIntVar(0, 365, 'days')
vacations = model.NewIntVar(0, 30, 'vacations')

for i in range(365 + 1):
    flag_bool = model.NewBoolVar(f'days == {i}')
    model.Add(days == i).OnlyEnforceIf(flag_bool)
    model.Add(days != i).OnlyEnforceIf(flag_bool.Not())
    model.Add(vacations == ceil(i * 30 / 365)).OnlyEnforceIf(flag_bool)

# test
model.Add(days == 300)

status = solver.Solve(model)

print(solver.Value(days), solver.Value(vacations))
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: A more general question would be if there is a better way to implement a precalculated arbitrary mapping of one variable to another.

Comment: I don't know about or-tools but it seems like you want a simple linear constraint? `vacations == days * 30/365`? The only thing would be having the ceiling but I'm pretty sure you don't need to add one constraint for each possible number of days... you may need a new variable to compute the reminder.

Comment: Yeah, the main problem is the ceiling, there should be a better way to do this, but haven't quite found it yet

Comment: First question, do you need an int_var? Why not an array of 365 bool_vars ?

Comment: Not a problem, working with booleans is better then?

Comment: Though, in my bigger problem days is pretty much a sum of boolvars

Comment: sum of boolvars are fast. What are the constraints on these sums? BTW, with you code, it is solved during presolve without any search.  On your question, either you use a boolean model, or an integer model. The integer model would be y = days * 30 + 364. Then AddDivisionEquality(vacation, y, 365), or a purely boolean model. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Solution following Laurent's suggestion:

```
ceil(days * 30 / 365) == (days * 30 + 364) // 365
```

Therefore

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

days = model.NewIntVar(0, 365, 'days')
vacations = model.NewIntVar(0, 30, 'vacations')
tmp = model.NewIntVar(364, 365 * 30 + 364, 'days*30+364')

model.Add(tmp == days * 30 + 364)
model.AddDivisionEquality(vacations, tmp, 365)

# test
model.Add(days == 300)

status = solver.Solve(model)

print(solver.Value(days), solver.Value(vacations))
```